# What's wrong with my code? Parsing through an input text file (C)

Tags: c, visual-studio, input, file-io, text-parsing

I need to read in an input file in this format:

```
REGISTERS
R1 4
R7 12
MEMORY
8 19
16 25
NEXT SECTION...
```

Where "R1 4" means register 1 has a value of 4, for example, or memory location 8 has value 19. I used 2 lines in each, but there can be any arbitrary number of registers and memory locations provided. For the first part of my project, I need to read in the input file and fill my arrays with the proper values (Ex. Registers[1] = 4). This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int parseFile(FILE *filePtr, int *registers, int *memory);
void parseRegisters(const char *line, int *registers);
void parseMemory(const char *line, int *memory);

void main() {
    int Registers[32];
    int Memory[1000];
    int returnVal;

    FILE* fileIn;
    fileIn = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fileIn == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to find input file\n");
        return;
    }

    returnVal = parseFile(fileIn, Registers, Memory);

    fclose(fileIn);
}


int parseFile(FILE *filePtr, int *registers, int *memory) {
    if (filePtr == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    char line[64];

    int mode = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, filePtr) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(line, "REGISTERS\n") == 0) {
            mode = 1;
            continue;
        }

        else if (strcmp(line, "MEMORY\n") == 0) {
            mode = 2;
            continue;
        }

        else {
            continue;
        }


        switch (mode) {
        case 1:
            parseRegisters(line, registers);
            break;
        case 2:
            parseMemory(line, memory);
            break;
        case 0: //will come back later for sections after MEMORY
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void parseRegisters(const char *line, int *registers) {
    int regNum, regVal;
    printf("test");

    if (sscanf(line, "R%d %d", &regNum, &regVal) != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid format for REGISTER section\n");
        return;
    }

    registers[regNum] = regVal;
    printf("%d %d", regNum, regVal); //was using to test if variables correctly set
    return;
}


void parseMemory(const char *line, int *memory) {
    int memLoc, memVal;

    if (sscanf(line, "%d %d", &memLoc, &memVal) != 2) {
        printf("Invalid format for MEMORY section\n");
        return;
    }

    memory[memLoc] = memVal;
    return;
}
```

This code is not finished for the later sections, but I've been testing just on the "Registers" part to no avail. When I run the code, "mode" is correctly updated, but I don't think parseRegisters() ever even executes because my printf() statements I left in there to test it doesn't print anything. I also tried printing the whole Registers[] array in main to see if it did get filled, but it's still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed it seems that your function parseRegisters will not be called.

This is because of your "continue" keywork inside your first switch structure.

As you can see here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ceyyskb.aspx, 
"continue" will make your while loop go to the next iteration. Therefore you will never reach your second switch structure if you get the words REGISTERS or MEMORY.

Try to remove "continue" keyword so the iteration inside the while loop will continue and check if it is better.

More generally when you have code, try to execute it line after line using a paper sheet and see what happens. If there is something you do not know (keyword, function, ...) try to google it as much as you can and see other example. If after having seriously googled you do not understand then Stack Overflow is here for you!

Answer (score 0):

..." I don't think parseRegisters() ever even executes"....

First of all, you should go step by step through the code using break points, then you can be sure whether code will be executed or not.

Second, make sure that the file path is correct. In your case the file has to be located in the same folder were your *.exe is or in the project folder.

Third, continue means, that you skip the code below it and start the loop again. -> Remove them...